# SSRS Report not rendering automatically unless View Report button is pressed (All parameters set to valid values)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

SSRS Report not rendering automatically unless View Report button is pressed (All parameters set to valid values).

As soon as user clicks on View Report, the report is rendered.

Actual requirement is to hide the parameters. However, since the report is not automatically rendered, hiding of parameters is just showing blank page without any output.

When parameters are shown, all parameter values are properly set to valid values and waiting for "View Report" button to be clicked.

Not sure what is the issue here.

Referenced similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58713415/data-will-not-show-if-view-report-button-isnt-clicked-in-ssrs). The solution suggested there is not applicable in my case as all the parameter values are correctly and no parameter has null values.

Comment: How are you populating the parameter values? Normally if a default value is set for all parameters, the report will run automatically.

Comment: Default values are set using data sets. All the parameters are set. Just needs to click on "View Report". I have many such reports where parameters are set by default, those are all working good except this one.

Comment: I've not seen this before but I've had inexplicable issues with parameters in the past. In some cases, I opened the RDL and found parameters configured that were not visible in Visual Studio and required manual editing. In some cases the order of the parameters was not as expected but after manually changing, the report behaved normally. Might be worth looking at the RDL and checking everything looks OK.

Comment: In-case any of the property is not set, the report would not work on click of "View Report" it will give missing property value exception.